# npm install module globally, but is ALREADY installed as global

Tags: module, npm

I will describe a weird situation.

there's a list of globally install modules

```
npm list -g --depth=0
/opt/node-v4.4.5-linux-x64/lib
├── cordova@6.2.0
└── npm@3.9.6
```

---

but when I try to build my project I get an error

```
npm install

npm WARN prefer global cordova@6.2.0 should be installed with -g
ctco-ecom-mobcockpit@0.1.0 /app/ctco-ecom-mobcockpit
└── cordova@6.2.0  extraneous

npm WARN optional Skipping failed optional dependency /karma/chokidar/fsevents:
npm WARN notsup Not compatible with your operating system or architecture: fsevents@1.0.12
npm WARN optional Skipping failed optional dependency /webpack/watchpack/chokidar/fsevents:
npm WARN notsup Not compatible with your operating system or architecture: fsevents@1.0.12
```

Answer (score 0):

I see the "errors" are WARN (warnings). That is, it installs successfully but not with full functionality (the optional dependency "fsevents" cannot load).

You need to find out some other package that does satisfy this dependency to get rid of the warning. If the package required it, it shouldn't have made it optional, otherwise it should work.

Your project might actually have issues due to that missing "fsevents" module.

Comment: OP was asking about the "npm WARN prefer global cordova..." message not the fsevents message